# WKWebView and InnerText with newline

Tags: javascript, c#, xamarin, xamarin.ios, wkwebview

I am currently working on implementing a web view inside of my iOS application using Xamarin. My webView is a WkWebView. My issue is that any time the text I am passing in has a new line it fails to display. However, testing my function in my browser (chrome) along with Safari I see that it executes just fine. I did some searching and I also tried to replace the \n character with \r\n, but that did not solve my issue. What am I missing?

C#:

```
private void BuildText(FormEntries entry, FormResponseAnswers formAnswers) {
            string function = "buildText('" + entry.Text + "', '" + formAnswers.Answer + "');";
            var javaScriptCmd = (NSString)function;

            webView.EvaluateJavaScript(javaScriptCmd, null);
        }
```

formAnswers.Answer that is causing the issue is:

```
"Hello world from the device, I do not know how well this will display our data at all. But we will see how this works. I wonder, if I were to add enter keys will it work?\n\n\nI kinda doubt it. ";
```

JS:

```
function buildText(entryText, answer) {
        var answerAreaDiv = document.getElementById('answerArea');
        var holder = document.createElement('div');
        holder.classList.add('holder');

        var entryLabel = document.createElement("label");
        entryLabel.textContent = entryText + ':';

        var answerLabel = document.createElement("label");

        answerLabel.innerText = answer;

        holder.appendChild(entryLabel);
        holder.appendChild(answerLabel);
        answerAreaDiv.appendChild(holder);
    }
```

HTML:

```
<body>  

    <div id="answerArea">
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: `innerText` is a quirky nonstandard property that IE introduced. It is highly recommended to instead use the standard, quicker, more reliable `textContent` instead - see http://perfectionkills.com/the-poor-misunderstood-innerText

Comment: @CertainPerformance textContent fails to work as well.

Comment: @SushiHangover the entire innerText; it appears as though that whole div does not get added as if i have my JS print how many labels i have it returns 6, if it was correct it would say 8

Answer (score 1):

HTML elements don't line break unless you explicitly ask them to; line breaks such as `\n` are treated as spaces. Try inserting HTML instead, so that you can replace your newline with a `<br>`:

`answerLabel.innerHTML = answer.replace(/\n/g, '<br>');`

Example:

```js
document.body.appendChild(document.createElement('label')).innerHTML = `first line
second line`.replace(/\n/g, '<br>');
```

Comment: No luck. This is very odd as it works fine inside of an html editor.

Comment: Actually found a neat work around, send in JSON data to my JS from the C#. Then the JSON will just parse it.

Comment: Are you sure you changed the attribute you're assigning to to `.innerHTML`?

Comment: Pretty sure I did. I can always try again later (work day over) to make sure i did not miss anything. I do appreciate the help.